# Texture isn't being applies to sphere in Next.js using Three

Tags: javascript, next.js, three.js

i'm trying to get a texture applied to a sphere inside of a nextjs component.

I've tried this with the code below but it will only show a black ball.

I've read it could be something to do with the texture being loaded in to late but i'm not sure.

```html
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1 / 1, 0.1, 100);
      camera.position.z = 20;

      // lights
      const aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.1);
      const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3);
      light.position.set(-10, 5, 5);
      scene.add(light);
      scene.add(aLight);

      const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 64, 64);
      const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("/earth_texture.jpg");
      texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;

      let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: texture,
        shininess: 100,
      });

      let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      sphere.castShadow = true;
      sphere.receiveShadow = true;
      scene.add(sphere);

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true,
        antialias: true,
      });
      renderer.setSize(500, 500);
      containerRef.current?.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`TextureLoader.load` is asynchronous. Just follow the example in the official documentation (see [`TextureLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader)):

```js
let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    shininess: 100,
});

const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    "/earth_texture.jpg",

    // onLoad callback
    function ( texture ) {
        material.map = texture;
        material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work, it did change the color of the ball to white. Could this be something nextjs specific?

Comment: @ruben No, this all has absolutely nothing to do with nextjs . Reduce the light: `new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.9);`

Comment: lowering the lights also don't seem to have any effect on it. 

`const aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.1);
      const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);`

Comment: @ruben So remove `texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace`. Anway, your problem is not reproducible. Are you sure that the texture can be loaded at all?